# inject and use services in program.cs pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

I have a service that I need to inject and use inside the project pipeline

```
//Register Service
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();

//Build App and Inject Service
var app = builder.Build();
var dbInitializer = app.Services.GetService<IDbInitializer>();

//Use 
dbInitializer.Initialize();
```

I will update the following problem when injecting this service (or any other service)

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eNCl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to require a scoped service, you need to initiate a scope inside which it will live: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#resolve-a-service-at-app-start-up

```cs
//Register Service
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();

//Build App and Inject Service
var app = builder.Build();
using (IServiceScope scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    IDbInitializer dbInitializer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();

    //Use 
    dbInitializer.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed
But I used the following code to get the service
` var dbInitializer = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();`

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I accidentally ommited the `.ServiceProvider` part. Will edit it in right away.